# Pointers, running out of memory, segmentation faults?

Tags: c, pointers

```
FILE *fp;
char *in;
char *sa[20];
char inn[100];

//other stuff here

for(huge loop) {
    fp = popen(filename, "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%100s", inn);
    in = strtok(inn, "=");
    i = 0;
    while(in != NULL) {
        sa[i++] = in;
        in = strtok (NULL, "=");
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs for about 4 minutes on my linux machine, as it sorts through huge data files, and then segmentation faults.  It runs correctly up until this point, and that point changes depending on how much I have it doing, so I strongly suspect a memory leak and that I should be freeing pointers.  But I thought without `malloc` the compiler allocates *and deallocates* pointer memory automatically.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you do `pclose`?

Comment: Also, you do know that `strtok` doesn't return unique pointers, and that it returns pointers to the string it tokenizes? That means *all* pointers in `sa` will point to different positions in `inn`. And if `inn` is a local variable and `sa` is not, then you have trouble ahead of you.

Comment: Not checking the return value of `popen()` is evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're leaving no room for a null terminator in the `inn` array.

There is no `pclose` for each `popen`.

You don't check the return value of `popen`.

There is no guarantee you won't overflow the `sa` array.

Comment: Pclose it is.  It now runs to completion.  Thanks!  I suppose I should be less lazy and check the values of inn and popen.  sa array cannot be overflowed with my data types (in theory).

Comment: @MatthewClarkson Data from external sources should never be trusted, especially when that trust may result in a crash. Why avoid one simple `if` test? Your program is undoubtedly I/O-bound so it would have 0% impact on performance. And without doubt `popen` can and will fail.  Not checking it is nuts.